# Angular 2, rc 4 radio-button to ng-model binding breaks

Tags: angular

Angular 2 radio-button to ng-model binding breaks.
Below is my code. It works the first time I change radio buttons. From second time selecting female has no effect.

```
      <radio-button [(ngModel)]="isMale" [value]="true" [label]="resource.mySiteDashboard_Male" name="isMale"></radio-button>
      <radio-button [(ngModel)]="isMale" [value]="false" [label]="resource.mySiteDashboard_Female" name="isMale"></radio-button>

 <div class="market-profile-content" *ngIf="isMale">
</div>
 <div class="market-profile-content" *ngIf="!isMale">
</div>
```

It worked fine in angular 2 rc-2

below is the template for the component.

```
<div class="radio">
    <input [(ngModel)]="value" type="radio" [id]="'radio-'+guid" [attr.name]="name" [disabled]="disabled" (change)="update()" />
    <label [attr.for]="'radio-'+guid">
        <span>{{label}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And the code

```
import {OnInit, Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, forwardRef, Provider} from '@angular/core'

import {NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor} from '@angular/forms';

const RADIO_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioButton),
    multi: true
});

@Component({
    selector: 'radio-button',
    templateUrl: './radioButton.html',
    providers: [RADIO_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class RadioButton implements ControlValueAccessor{
    @Input() value: boolean;
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() disabled: boolean;
    @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    guid: string;
    model: any;
    checked: boolean;

    onModelChange: Function = () => { };
    onModelTouched: Function = () => { };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.guid = this.generateGuid();
    }

    generateGuid() {
        ...         
    }

    update() {
        if (!this.disabled) {
            this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
            this.onModelChange(this.value);
        }
    }

    writeValue(model: any): void {
        this.model = model;
        this.checked = (this.model == this.value);
    }

    registerOnChange(func: Function): void {
        this.onModelChange = func;
    }

    registerOnTouched(func: Function): void {
        this.onModelTouched = func;
    }

}
```

Comment: `radio-button` is custom component created by you, or Ionic?